# Angular 6 error: JSONP injected script did not invoke callback

Tags: angular, angular6, jsonp, angular-httpclient

Working on an Angular 6 project and trying to access a public API so I need to use JSONP to get around CORS. Been getting the following error with my code:
"Error: JSONP injected script did not invoke callback".
I believe it is a problem with the name of the callback parameter.

I've spent a good amount of time looking at similar problems here and on Github, most notably this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8153 and have tried replacing JSONP_CALLBACK with:

> **ng_jsonp**.__req${this.times}.finished
>
> __ng_jsonp____req6_finished
>
> and just omitting the callback parameter altogether

But I am yet to find success.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

export class CoursesAPIService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getData() {
        var url = 'http://web-app.usc.edu/web/soc/api/classes/?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK'
        console.log("calling: " + url)

        return this.http.jsonp(url, "callback")
           .pipe(map(data => {
               console.log("Inside map")

               console.log(data)
           })
        ).subscribe()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it turned out for me when using HttpClient.jsonp() that you shouldn't pass the callback=JSONP_CALLBACK parameter and value.

```
// try this instead
var url = 'http://web-app.usc.edu/web/soc/api/classes/?'
```

if you check the source code in the angular github https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/client.ts

at line <s>1121</s> 1461 (**since this section is being worked on still just do a search for the jsonp() function**) you'll notice they will send that parameter again. and your current url variable will turn into:

```
// this is what's probably giving you issues after the jsonp function's internal functions are processed 
'http://web-app.usc.edu/web/soc/api/classes/?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK'
```